# List comprehension with multiple conditions on different columns

Tags: python, pandas, list-comprehension

I have the following df,

```
data = [['Male', 'Agree'], ['Male', 'Agree'], ['Male', 'Disagree'], ['Female','Neutral']]
 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Sex', 'Opinion'])
df
```

& would like to get the total number of Male who either Agree or Disagree. I expect the answer to be 3 but instead get 9.

```
sum([True for x in df['Opinion'] for y in df['Sex'] if x in ['Agree','Disagree'] if y=='Male' ]
```

I have done this through other methods and I'm trying to understand list comprehension better.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to iterate through two lists in parallel?](/q/1663807/4518341) I know it says "lists", but it works the same for Series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's unpack this a bit. The original statement

```py
total = sum([True for x in df['Opinion'] for y in df['Sex'] if x in ['Agree','Disagree'] if y=='Male' ]
```

is equivalent to

```py
total = 0
for x in df['Opinion']:
    for y in df['Sex']:
        if x in ['Agree', 'Disagree']:
            if y=='Male':
                total += 1
```

I think it should be clear in this case why you get `9`.

What you actually want is to only consider corresponding pairs of two equal sized iterables. There's the handy `zip` built-in in python which does just this,

```py
total = 0
for x,y in zip(df['Opinion'], df['Sex']):
    if x in ['Agree', 'Disagree'] and y=='Male':
        total += 1
```

or as a comprehension

```py
total = sum(1 for x,y in zip(df['Opinion'], df['Sex']) if x in ['Agree', 'Disagree'] and y=='Male')
```

Comment: And also, you don't use list comprehension at the end, right :) I think OP noticed that since they accepted so I leave now.

Comment: @Neither hehe, yeah I switched it for a generator since I can't bring myself to recommend constructing the full list only for it to be immediately reduced by a sum. Thought it might make things confusing to add that discussion in the answer.